# Specify default values for instance variables outside constructor

Tags: ruby, inheritance, instance-variables

My goal is to initialize an instance variable without making use of the initialize method.
I have this code:

```
class Animal
  attr_reader :age
  def initialize(age)
    @age = age
  end
end

class Sheep < Animal
  attr_accessor :likes
  def initialize(age)
    super
    @likes = []
  end
end

sheep = Sheep.new(5)
sheep.likes << "grass"
```

The `initialize` method in this subclass calls `super`. This doesn't scale very nicely: If I change the signature of the superclass, I have to adjust it in all subclasses as well.

It would be nicer if I can initialize an instance variable like `@likes = []` outside of the `initialize` method within the class scope of `Sheep`, like many other OO-languages can. However, that would make my variable an instance variable of the class object.

Here's a way I discovered that doesn't override the constructor:

```
class Sheep < Animal
  attr_accessor :likes
  def likes
    @likes || @likes = []
  end
end
```

That's much more elegant because readjusting signatures is not necessary, but it's still not perfect: Wouldn't Ruby check for non-`nil`-ness of `likes` when I access that instance variable? Is there a way to do this without sacrificing runtime or code elegance?

Comment: The real issue is not that instance variables are different from class instance variables. Even if you initialize a class variable or a constant in the class body, using that (pushing elements into it) in instance methods means that you are modifying a shared array from different objects. That does not seem to make sense.

Comment: @sawa May I ask what the comment is referring to? I know that initializing a class variable in the class body gives me a different behaviour, that's what I meant with "as other OO-languages can". I was mostly looking for a elegant solution in Ruby, that allows me to essentially get the behaviour of member variables in Java, without having to worry about rewriting code later.

Comment: @sawa Btw, I took the freedom to re-add some phrases of the edit you made. I agree that my question was longer than necessary, but I feel like some clarity of the motivation behind the question got lost. (Also, it probably sounded like I was firing shots at Ruby. I actually meant to fire shots at my code. Whoops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is call a method from the `initialize` of `Animal`, providing a hook for subclasses to add custom functionality:

```
class Animal
  attr_reader :age
  def initialize(age)
    @age = age

    setup_defaults
  end

  private
  def setup_defaults
    # NOOP by default
  end
end

class Sheep < Animal
  attr_accessor :likes

  private
  def setup_defaults
    @likes = []
  end
end
```

A second way, that you mention in your post, you can do this is use a custom `def likes` instead of the `attr_reader`/`attr_accessor`:

```
def likes
  @likes ||= [] # shorter way of doing what you have
end
```

As a third option, if you don't mind using `initialize` (your primary concern seems to be possibly changing the superclass' signature), since you don't care about any the parameters to initialize`Sheep` is you can overwrite the `initialize` like:

```
class Sheep < Animal
  attr_accessor :likes
  def initialize(*)
    super
    @likes = []
  end
end
```

this is the same as doing something like `def initialize(*args)` except you don't name the variable, and works since `super` passes in the original arguments by default. Now, if you go back and change animal to have, say, a `name` argument to its `initialize`:

```
class Animal
  attr_reader :age, :name
  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end
end
```

`Sheep` still works without any changes.

Answer (score 2):

In your final example:

```
class Sheep < Animal
  attr_accessor :likes

  def likes
    @likes || @likes = []
  end
end
```

you're essentially using memoization, although your syntax is a little different from the norm, which would look like:

```
def likes
  @likes ||= []
end
```

Additionally, because you have `likes` now as a memoized method, and not an attribute of the instance, you do not need `attr_accessor` (or `attr_reader`, etc.).

```
class Sheep < Animal
  def likes
    @likes ||= []
  end
end
```

And you're good to go.

Edit: Per your concern of performance:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'benchmark'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> @hello = []
=> []
[3] pry(main)> def hello
[3] pry(main)*   @hello
[3] pry(main)* end
=> :hello
[4] pry(main)> def likes
[4] pry(main)*   @likes ||= []
[4] pry(main)* end
=> :likes
[5] pry(main)> puts Benchmark.measure { 1_000_000.times { hello } }
  0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.071330)
=> nil
[6] pry(main)> puts Benchmark.measure { 1_000_000.times { likes } }
  0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.097388)
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

With experimental patch you can do:

```
class Zaloop

  attr_accessor var1: :default_value, var2: 2

  def initialize
    self.initialize_default_values
  end

end

puts Zaloop.new.var1 # :default_value
```

- Please be aware, patch below - is experimental solution, be careful if you decide to use it on production

Patch for module:

```
Module.module_eval do

  alias _original_attr_accessor attr_accessor
  def attr_accessor(*args)
    @default_values ||= {}
    attr_names = []
    args.map do |arg|
      if arg.is_a? Hash
        arg.each do |key, value|
          define_default_initializer if @default_values.empty?
          @default_values[key] = value
          attr_names << key
        end
      else
        attr_names << arg
      end
    end
    _original_attr_accessor *attr_names
  end

  def define_default_initializer
    default_values = @default_values
    self.send :define_method, :initialize_default_values do
      default_values.each do |key, value|
        instance_variable_set("@#{key}".to_sym, value)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Please, never use it in production. never.